# print sha in every line of git log

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to print git log in this format:

```
# sha subject: body
8c75408 commit a: this is a first line of commit a
8c75408 commit a: this is a second line of commit a
5b710e0 commit b: this is a first line of commit b
c59982e commit c: this is a first line of commit c
```

You may notice, this is a very similar format to `grep --with-filename`.

That is, it prints all commit comments with prefixed sha (or other formatted string), so that I can grep for a particular line in comments easily with `| grep 'second line'`. For example,

```
# after grep
8c75408 commit a: this is a second line of commit a
```

Some possible options are:

- `git log --format='%h %s' --grep 'second line'` is most similar to what I want, except that it does not print the actual line that it is matched.

  ```
  # output
  8c75408 commit a
  ```
- `git log --format='%h %s:%n%b' --grep 'second line'` does print all commit message of matched commit.

  ```
  # output
  8c75408 commit a:
  this is a first line of commit a
  this is a second line of commit a
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alias in my `.gitconfig` as

```
[alias]

    lg = log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

running a `git lg` on meld's repository gives the following output:

[image]

If this is what you wanted, also I recommend using a GUI, `gitk` is a good one.

Comment: OP wants to display the full commit message though, with each line being annotated by the commit hash.

Comment: @poke Oh I didn't saw that... sorry